# Show an inequality in three variables

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, majorization

Problem :

Let $a,b,c>0$ then we have :

$$\left[4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ab}\right)}{a+b+c}\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}abc-\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^{3}< 0$$

My Attempt :

We use a Theorem A :

Theorem A :

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3\in(0,\infty)$ and $u>0$ a real then if we have :

$$x_1^u+x_2^u+x_3^u\geq y_1^u+y_2^u+y_3^u$$

And for $i\neq j,1\leq i\leq 3,1\leq j\leq 3$:

$$|x_i^u-x_j^u|\leq |y_i^u-y_j^u|$$

Then we have :

$$x_1x_2x_3\geq y_1y_2y_3$$

To use the theorem A we set :

$$y_1=\left[4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ab}\right)}{a+b+c}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{ab}$$

$$y_2=\left[4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ab}\right)}{a+b+c}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{bc}$$

$$y_3=\left[4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ab}\right)}{a+b+c}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{ca}$$

And :

$$x_2=x_3=x_1=\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)$$

With the choose of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ we reach one of the constraint .

Here $u=0.00625$.

So we have to show after homogeneization:

$$\left(4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}\right)}{b+a+1}\right)^{\frac{u}{2}}\left(b^{\frac{1}{2}u}+\left(ba\right)^{\frac{1}{2}u}+a^{\frac{1}{2}u}\right)-\frac{3\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{u}{6}}\left(1+a+b\right)^{u}}{3^{u}}\leq 0$$

Or :

$$\left(4-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}\right)}{b+a+1}\right)^{\frac{u}{2}}\left(b^{\frac{1}{2}u}+\left(ba\right)^{\frac{1}{2}u}+a^{\frac{1}{2}u}\right)\leq \frac{3\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{u}{6}}\left(1+a+b\right)^{u}}{3^{u}}$$

Or $a\to a^2$,$b\to b^2$:

$$\left(4-\frac{3\left(ab+b+a\right)}{b^{2}+a^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(a^{u}+b^{u}+\left(ab\right)^{u}\right)^{\frac{1}{u}}-\frac{3^{\frac{1}{u}}\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\left(1+a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}{3}\leq 0$$

Now we have the inequality :

$$\left(4-\frac{3\left(ab+b+a\right)}{b^{2}+a^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(a^{u}+b^{u}+\left(ab\right)^{u}\right)^{\frac{1}{u}}-\frac{3^{\frac{1}{u}}\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\left(1+a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}{3}\leq \left(4-\frac{3\left(ab+b+a\right)}{b^{2}+a^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(a+b+\left(ab\right)\right)-\frac{3\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(1+a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}{3}\tag{1}$$

Or $x\in[0,1]$:

$$\left(4-3x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}x-\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\leq 0$$

Where :

$$x=\frac{ab+b+a}{b^{2}+a^{2}+1}$$

Wich is is obvious .

Some remarks :

I cannot explain or show all the steps notably $(1)$ so how to explain that and have you an other path to show it ?

Answer (score -1):

Almost half an answer .

We have for $0<a=b\leq 1$ and $x\in[0,1]$ :

$$-\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\left(1+x^{2}+a^{2}\right)}{3}\right)^{2}}{\left(\frac{x^{u}}{3}+\frac{a^{u}}{3}+\frac{\left(xa\right)^{u}}{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{u}}}\le-\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\left(1+x^{2}+b^{2}\right)}{3}\right)^{2}}{\left(\frac{1+2\left(xb\right)^{u}}{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{u}}}\tag{i}$$

So remains to show an inequality with variable $xb=U$ and $x+b=Y$ wich is easier to tackle .We can use $ab1$'s method .

It's not hard using $i$ that the difference for fixed sum $a+b=\alpha$ is maximized for $a=b=\alpha/2$ so we need to show for positive $x$:

$$\left(4-\frac{3\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\left(1+2\left(\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)^{u}\right)}{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{u}}-\frac{\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}}{3^{2}}<0$$

Setting $u\to 0$ we get the inequality :

$$\frac{\left(4-\frac{3\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\right)x^{\frac{8}{3}}}{4\cdot2^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{\left(\frac{16}{9\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}}{3^{2}}<0$$

See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor%20%5Cfrac%7B%284-%5Cfrac%7B3%28x%5E3%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B6%7D%7D%7B4%7D%29%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B6%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D%29x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B8%7D%7B1%7D%7D%7D%7B4%5Ccdot2%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D-%5Cfrac%7B%28%5Cfrac%7B16%7D%7B9%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%5Cleft%281%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B6%7D%7D%7B2%7D%29%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B3%5E%7B2%7D%7D)

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+ln%28%284-%5Cfrac%7B3%28x%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B4%7D%29%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D%29%28%5Cfrac%7B%281%2B2%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B4%7D%29%5E%7Bu%7D%29%7D%7B3%7D%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bu%7D%7D%29-ln%28%5Cfrac%7B%28%5Cfrac%7B16%7D%7B9%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%281%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B2%7D%29%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B3%5E%7B2%7D%7D%29